# check if img loaded successfully or not using php

Tags: php, image, loaded

How to check if the image loaded or not using php.

i'm using this

```
<img onload="myFunction1()" onerror="myFunction2()" src="https://www.google.com/img.png">
```

but Need it pure php not html tags

Comment: loaded where, when? This is a very imprecise and vaguely worded question at this point in time. Please edit to improve your question and to clarify what you're trying to achieve and how you're trying to achieve it....

Comment: Why is it tagged `php`?

Comment: @Jocelyn the asker wants a PHP solution to a (seemingly) Javascript/browser based problem.

Comment: At client side you cannot check that with PHP, you could to that on uploading to server or if the client that requested the page also requested the image (and it was not blocked or not asked for by e.g. a text-based browser). but you lack to specify what exactly you want to do when where and with what.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How to check if the image loaded or not using php.
>   i'm using this 
>   `<img onload="myFunction1()" onerror="myFunction2()" src="https://www.google.com/img.png">`
>
> but Need it pure php not html tags

Some points:

1) It looks like you're trying to check the image is loaded *in the browser*, this **can not be done with PHP** because PHP is server-side and only the *output* of PHP code is sent to the browser.

2) Why are you trying to use PHP when javascript should do?

3) If you have some obscure technical requirement for the test to be PHP then you *could* do it using some `AJAX` requests but it would be horrifically inefficient compared to simply having some browser-run javascript without needing to converse with the server, again.

- It is worth noting even if you did construct a PHP + Javscript based ajax test for if an image was loaded by a browser; the result would be useless because the result could not be actioned by PHP as previously stated, PHP works on the page ***before*** the page reaches the client browser.
  It's like drinking a whole cup of coffee and only then telling the Barista that it was too hot.

4) Use Javascript.

**You can do this check *before* the page is sent to the browser**:

If you simply want to check that `https://www.google.com/img.png` exists and is accessible you *can* do this in PHP; with some caveats. You can [use `cURL`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/981954/how-can-one-check-to-see-if-a-remote-file-exists-using-php) (read the [top three answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/981954/how-can-one-check-to-see-if-a-remote-file-exists-using-php) they're all useful) Or you can use PHP `getimagesize` or `get_headers` as outlined in [this answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14806159/how-do-i-test-if-an-remote-image-file-exists-in-php).

Once you have established if the image specified is valid and reachable you can then use PHP to choose an outcome and change the contents of the page sent to the browser, **before the page is sent**, typically with an `if` statement to display different images depending on their validity.